# Tangent space of an algebraic variety $ X $ in a point $ x \in X $.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety, and $ \mathcal{O}_{X,x} $ its local ring at a point $x \in X$, and $  \mathfrak{m}_x $ its maximal ideal. Let set $ k_x = \mathcal{O}_{X,x} / \mathfrak{m}_x $ the residue field  and $ \epsilon_x $ the morphism of algebras : $ \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to k_x $, the evaluation in $x$ definded by : $ \epsilon_x (f) = f(x) $.

As we can say : $ \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \simeq \mathfrak{m}_x \oplus \mathcal{O}_{X,x} / \mathfrak{m}_x = \mathfrak{m}_x \oplus k(x) = \mathfrak{m}_x \oplus k.1 $

It's follows that : $ \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^* \simeq \mathfrak{m}_{x}^* \oplus k^* \simeq \mathfrak{m}_{X}^* \oplus k^k $
and : $ \mathfrak{m}_{x}* = \{ f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^* \ / \  f \not \in k^k \ \} = \{ \ f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^* \ / \  f(1) = 0 \ \}   $

In my book which i'm learning actually, the author say without explanation, that : $ ( \mathfrak{m}_x / \mathfrak{m}_{x}^2 )^* = \{ \ f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^*  \ / \ f(1 ) = 0 = f ( \mathfrak{m}_{x}^{2} ) \ \} $

Could you explain me in detail, why please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is $k^k$ here?

Comment: it's $ k^k = \{ \ f : k \to k \ | \ f \ \text{ is linear } \ \} $.  :-)

Comment: I found the answear alone. :-) Indeed : $ \mathfrak{m}_x / m_{x}^{2} $ represent the functor : $ F : k \to F(k) = \{ \ f : \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to k \ | \ f(1) = 0 = f ( m_{x}^{2} ) \ \} $, so $ \forall f \in F(k) \ \ \exists ! g : m_x / m_{x}^2 $ : $ f = g \circ \pi $ such that $ \pi : O_{X,x} \to m_x \to m_x / m_{x}^2 $.  :-)